# Where to start in Prayer? If someone enters in Prayer with a group of people praying together.

Tags: salat, jamaat

I want to ask question related to Prayer. It is considered more valuable if group of muslims pray "Faraz" together in the leadership of "imam". And one want to join them, while they have completed "2 or 3 rakaats". Where should he start if others who started together are sitting on there knees. Where should new comer start from. Should he read what others are reading at that position or sit silently without reading any thing. Please suggest me some authentic books which will help me to correct my Prayer

Comment: If you are looking for an authentic book, perhaps this [english pdf](http://www.islamguiden.com/arkiv/en_The_Prophets_Prayer_Albaani.pdf) would help

Comment: some authentic guidelines about prayer: [Prayer (Salat): According to Five Islamic Schools of Law](http://www.al-islam.org/shiite-encyclopedia-ahlul-bayt-dilp-team/prayer-salat-according-five-islamic-schools-law-part-1)